# PHP imagejpeg() problems

Tags: php, debugging, gd

I had an image upload script that worked on my little shared hosting, but just as I switched to Virt Ded, it immediately stopped working. After some research I determined the culprit to be the PHP function imagejpeg() - which was the last bit of code in the script.

It allows me to specify null as the filepath (in which case it prints it to the screen), but does not allow me to enter ANY filepath without return false.

Anybody know what is going on?

Comment: you know, i just checked that, and made sure that all my folders have full permissions...read write execute....777, right?

Comment: Is the error\_reporting set to E\_ALL or higher? Any error/warning/notice messages?

Comment: yes, it is at E_ALL for the moment...is there a better one to try?

Comment: however...E_ALL isn't returning any of the errors that i normally would be ale to trigger....weird

Comment: Then try `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); echo THISHSOULDRAISEANOTICE; imagejpeg(....`

Answer (score 1):

First I would see if the PHP install contains all the libgd stuff you need for imagejpeg().

You can check like this:

```
$extensions = get_loaded_extensions();

if( !in_array( 'gd', $extensions ) )
{
  die "libgd is not loaded";
}
```

If that's good to go you can do something like:

```
$gd = gd_info();

while( list( $k, $v ) = each( $gd ) )
{
  echo "$k: $v";
}
```

Make sure you see some jpeg stuff listed, if there is none you need some dependent libraries installed.