# Unable to make directory (mkdir) in DirectAdmin

Tags: php, codeigniter, mkdir

I'm new in DirectAdmin. I'm facing a problem that when user try to create a folder, they will get error, `"Unable to upload data."` (refer to my code).

I think my code should be no problem as it can run smoothly in Localhost. The problem rise when I run on live server (DirectAdmin).

```
    $id = $this->session->userdata('id');
    $directory = "./image/userFolder/" . $id;

    if(!is_dir($directory)) {
      mkdir($directory, 0777, true);
    }

   $directory = $directory . "/" . $nameImage;

   if(!imagejpeg($big_image, $directory)) {
     $data['error'] = "Unable to upload data.";
     return $data;
   }
```

Hope to get answer or maybe something that I can look after. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not familiar with DirectAdmin but this seems to be an `imagejpeg` specific problem. Is libgd+ included in the PHP installation on the server? Some tips for debugging can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8953333/156755) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2032255/156755)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I managed to solve my problem my changing the permission in FTP from 0755 to 0777. So the answer is changing the FTP permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem. Basically my folder's permission is 0755. Then I change to 0777 that enable user to make folder (mkdir) in the server. You can learn more about permission [here](http://www.php.net/chmod).